# I am trying to install pandas for Python3.3 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, numpy

I had installed Python2.7 and was trying to install numpy and pandas for the same. However when I saw Python3.3 was already there, I removed the 2.7 and related packages and installed numpy for python 3. But when I tried installing pandas I started getting this error

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-setuptools.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python setuptools.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing python-setuptools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-setuptools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried a bunch of things like

1. `apt-get -f install`
2. `apt-get install -y python-central`. Nothing seems to work out

Any help/suggestions would be very helpful. I am completely new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the postinstallation script for [`python-setuptools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-setuptools) can't find `pycompile`, which compiles Python source to bytecode. `pycompile` is part of the [`python-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-minimal) package. You may want to try uninstalling all the Python packages you have currently then going step-by-step, installing:

1. [`python2.7`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python2.7) (which will install [`python-minimal`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-minimal), which contains `pycompile`)
2. [`python-setuptools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-setuptools) (which uses `pycompile`)
3. [`python-pandas`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-pandas) (which presumably uses [`python-setuptools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-setuptools))